# Force a System.Array when reading a XML file with only one element in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, xml, powershell

So the problem is that if I have a XML file with only one element I can't access to it like if it was an array of dimension 1. Because PowerShell read it as a `System.Xml.XmlLinkedNode` instead of a `System.Array`.

How can I force it to be read as an array of 1 item?

Reading this XML file:

```
<batch>
  <project name="test">
    <locPrj>locPrj</locPrj>
    <locFolder>locFolder</locFolder>
    <plan name="Plan 01" exec="1" />
  </project>
</batch>
```

Does not allow me to call it as:

```
[xml]$mainXML = Get-Content -Path "C:\test.xml"
$mainXML.batch.project[0] # This returns nothing!
$mainXML.batch.project.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                          
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                          
True     False    XmlElement                               System.Xml.XmlLinkedNode
```

However this XML, it allows me:

```
<batch>
  <project name="test">
    <locPrj>locPrj</locPrj>
    <locFolder>locFolder</locFolder>
    <plan name="Plan 01" exec="1" />
  </project>
  <project name="test2">
    <locPrj>locPrj2</locPrj>
    <locFolder>locFolder2</locFolder>
    <plan name="Plan 01" exec="0" />
  </project>
</batch>
```

I have been looking for a command to force an array for that node but I haven't found anyone. Any idea?

```
[xml]$mainXML = Get-Content -Path "C:\test2.xml"
$mainXML.batch.project[0] # This the first project called test
$mainXML.batch.project.GetType()
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                          
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                          
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

Answer (score 4):

Just *cast* the node to an *array* using `@()`:

```
@($mainXML.batch.project)[0]
```

Comment: The thing is that I have a for loop going in each "project" and modifying their elements. Like having a dummy variable $nInt in $mainXML.batch.project[$nInt], and with this solution I would just introduce it into an array, but when I have several projects, I would have an array inside of an array.